# how to pull in gtm variable from site code

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am looking to pull in certain variables from the below code on a basket page to GTM. I need assistance with what type of javascript code would accomplish this.

```
<div id="productDetailsJSON_15410178" class="hidden">
    {
        'id': '85567',
        'name': 'awareness underwire bra',
        'category': 'not set',
        'list': 'not set',
        'position': 'not set',
        'brand': 'wacoal',
        'price': '65.00',
        'quantity': '1',
        'variant': 'midnight blue',
        'dimension1': '85567.488.36C',
        'dimension2': '36c',
        'dimension7': '',
        'dimension8': '36',
        'dimension9': 'c'
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [DOM type GTM variable](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#8-dom-element) where you set the selector to `#productDetailsJSON_15410178`. This would return the innerText of the matched element.

If you wanted to extract individual values you'd have to use that in a [Custom Javascript variable](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#4-custom-javascript) and parse the variable contents into JSON. That would be a bit problematic, since the content of that variable is not actually a JSON string (JSON requires double quotes), so you could not just do a JSON.parse - you'd need to replace the single quotes with double quotes beforehand. That's a little messy, so it would be easier if you could fix your string beforehand.